# AttributeError in calling user-defined Python exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I am trying to do exception handling mainly from [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html). I am facing  a weird problem: the directory contains `main.py` and `exceptions.py`.

In `exceptions.py` (with no import statements) I define my exception class as follows:

```
class ConvergenceError(AssertionError):
    def __init__(self,dc_places):
        self.decimal_places = dc_places
    def __str__(self):
        return 'convergence of R_inf is not correct to ', self.decimal_places
```

In `main.py` I have this import statement:

```
import exceptions as ex
```

and I call the exception as follows:

```
try:
    np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(R_inf,R_itr,4)
    raise ex.ConvergenceError(4) 
except ex.ConvergenceError as ce :  
    print str(ce)
```

I receive the following error:

```
    except ex.ConvergenceError as ce :  
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ConvergenceError'
```

I can not figure out why the interpreter can't see `Convergence` in the `exceptions.py` module.

Comment: Does `print ex.__file__` give the result you expect? Is there a `exceptions.pyc` file in the directory?

Comment: I do not know what does ex.__file__ do but when I ran it nothing changed. And
There is no exceptions.pyc file in my directory

Comment: If you `print ex.__file__`, as I suggested, it will show you what file `ex` refers to, which may not be the one you expect. You could also try `print dir(ex)` to see what attributes *are* defined in that module.

Comment: print dir(ex) gave me: ['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError', 'BaseException', 'BufferError', 'BytesWarning', 'DeprecationWarning'..]

Sorry I am not used to the formatting of stackoverflow

Comment: Then you are not importing the module you think you are. Try naming the file with your custom exception something different (like `custom_exceptions.py`) and importing from that.

Comment: `print ex.__file__` gave me the same error :

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'

Comment: When I changed it to Myexceptions.py , it worked ! Thanks a lot.

But would you mind explain why did this error occur ?

Comment: Because `import exceptions as ex` refers to the built-in `exceptions` module (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html), rather than your file `exceptions.py`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have discussed with [**`jonrsharpe`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442564/attributeerror-in-calling-user-defined-python-exception#comment52749139_32442564), your problem is that you are actually importing a built-in module `exceptions`. Try the following:

```
>>> import exceptions
>>> exceptions
<module 'exceptions' (built-in)>
```

So what you can do is simply rename your module (e.g. to `ex.py`) and you'll be good:

```
>>> import ex
...
```

Answer (score 3):

I would just like to elaborate that exceptions is actually a C-builtin, and is loaded upon the start of the interpreter (this is only true on Python2 and not Python3, for Python3 it is found in [builtins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030933/python-2s-exceptions-module-is-missing-in-python3-where-did-its-contents-go)):

```
 >>> import sys
 >>> [i for i in sys.modules if 'exceptions' in i]
 ['exceptions']
 >>> import exceptions   # dictionary lookup to builtin
 <module 'exceptions' (built-in)>
```

Exceptions has no path and is automatically in the current path for fairly obvious reasons: the interpreter itself, from the core libraries, requires exception handling. This means if you try to import exceptions via any standard approach, you will import the builtin and not your custom module you want.

For example, here I have exceptions.py in the path and try to load it via a standard import.

```
>>> [i for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if 'except' in i]
['exceptions.py']
>>> import exceptions
<module 'exceptions' (built-in)>
exceptions = __import__("exceptions")
>>> exceptions
<module 'exceptions' (built-in)>
```

You cannot even reload it to force it into the interpreter.

```
>>> reload(exceptions)
<module 'exceptions' (built-in)>
```

You can absolutely force it if you use IMP and a custom full path.

```
>>> imp.load_source('exceptions', os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'exceptions.py'))
<module 'exceptions' from '/home/alex/exceptions.py'>
```

EDIT: I should also mention that this does not override the builtin exceptions class except in the current namespace. Doing a from module import package still refers to the builtin even after the exceptions name has been overridden. Python wisely does not let you shoot yourself in the foot.

```
>>> exceptions
<module 'exceptions' from '/home/alex/exceptions.pyc'>
>>> from exceptions import BaseException
>>> BaseException
<type 'exceptions.BaseException'>
```